# Paying bills in Alphagonia

Tags: mathematics, number-theory

In the Kingdom of Alphagonia, where the national currency is the *Alpha*, banknotes are available in all whole-number denominations of alphas: 1, 2, 3,...

a) What is the least number of such notes a citizen of Alphagonia needs top carry in her wallet if she wishes to be certain that she will be able to pay any amount between 1 and 100 alphas without requiring any change?

For example, if she carries 19 notes (nine 1-alpha notes, one 10-alpha notes, and nine 11-alpha notes) she can pay any amount in that range, but is this best possible?

b) What is the least number of notes she will require if she wishes to pay any amount in the range 1 to *N*, *N* any positive integer?

Comment: Isn't this pretty obviously about $\log_2 N$? Original can be done in 7 notes: 1,2,4,8,16,32,64

Comment: @JeremyDover rot13(V gubhtug gurer zvtug or fbzr erqhaqnapl orpnhfr guvf tvirf hc gb bar gjb frira, ohg gur zbfg inyhrf gung pna or pbirerq jvgu fvk abgrf vf fvkgl guerr. Ubjrire gurer ner inevbhf inyhrf sbe gur hccre guerr abgrf gung jbex).

Answer (score 8):

Here is a proof of optimality.

For general $N$, we need

> $\lceil\log_2(N + 1)\rceil$

notes, which can be chosen as

> notes of values $2^0, 2^1, \dots, 2^{k - 1}$ where $k = \lceil\log_2(N + 1)\rceil$.

These can, in an obvious way, be used for any number between $1$ and $N$.

To prove that this is optimal:

> with $m$ notes, there can be at most $2^m$ different representable numbers, as this is the number of subsets of the notes.
>
>  And of course the empty set has a value of $0$, so together with $1, \dots, N$, we get the inequality: $ N + 1 \leq 2^m$, which translates to $m \geq \lceil\log_2(N + 1)\rceil$.
>
>
>  Note: it's the same as the answer of @hexomino: $N + 1\leq 2^m \iff N \leq 2^m - 1 \iff N < 2^m$, hence the smallest $m$ such that $2^m \geq N + 1$ is one plus the largest $m$ such that $2^m \leq N$.

Answer (score 7):

I may be missing something but I think the answer to (a) is

> **7** notes
>  which can be achieved by carrying around 1 note of each of the powers of 2 less than 100 - 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64. For a given amount she would then just need its binary representation and select one of each of the notes represented by a 1.

And (b) would then be

> Generalising this approach she would only need $$\lfloor \log_2  N \rfloor +1 $$ notes to achieve any amount between 1 and N.

See the answer of WhatsUp for a proof of optimality

Comment: Nice! You could add a proof of optimality.

Comment: @Magma Sorry I went away for a bit. WhatsUp seems to have it covered now.

Comment: I was actually typing that answer when @Magma made this comment (: